# how to add pixel value to 100% padding value

Tags: react-native

I have a react native project , I want to add a pixel value to '90%' value of a stylesheet paddingBottom, 
 I have tested:

```
paddingBottom: '90%' + 20,
```

It didn't Work could you please help ?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do, edit the question and post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you’re wanting to set the bottom padding to be 90% of the height of the screen this can be accomplished without having to install any additional dependencies.

Add to where your styles are:

`import { Dimensions} from 'react-native'`

and get the height of the window

`const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;`

Then when setting your padding you can do the following

```
paddingBottom: height * 0.9 + 20
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to install this module [react-native-extended-stylesheet](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet#percents)

example:

```
const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
    column: {
      width: '100% - 20'
    }
  });
```

or you can also use flex

> Use flex in a component's style to have the component expand and
>   shrink dynamically based on available space. Normally you will use
>   flex: 1, which tells a component to fill all available space, shared
>   evenly amongst other components with the same parent. The larger the
>   flex given, the higher the ratio of space a component will take
>   compared to its siblings.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width#flex-dimensions